# Mocking a function that is passed in as a parameter during a class variable initialization

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

[scuevals_api/resources/students.py](https://github.com/SCUEvals/scuevals-api/blob/master/scuevals_api/resources/students.py):

```
def year_in_range(year):
    return datetime.now().year <= year <= datetime.now().year + 10


class StudentsResource(Resource):
    args = {
        'graduation_year': fields.Int(required=True, validate=year_in_range),
    }

    ...
```

I'm trying to mock `year_in_range` (to always return True) however, all my attempts have failed so far.

I'm using the decorator approach with `mock.patch` and have tried a ton of different targets, but the one I believe should be the correct one is:
`@mock.patch('scuevals_api.resources.students.year_in_range', return_value=True)`

The mock function never gets called, as in, it's not mocking correctly. I'm not getting any errors either.

My only remaining suspicions is that it has something to do with that the function is passed in to `fields.Int` as a param (hence the question title), but in my head, it shouldn't affect anything.

I'm clueless as to where this function should be mocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the explanation by Chris Hunt, I came up with an alternative solution. It does modify the application code rather than the testing code, but if that is acceptable (which, in today's day and age probably should be, since having testable code is high priority), it is a really simple solution:

It's not possible to mock `year_in_range` since a reference to the original function is saved before the mocking is done. Therefore, "wrap" the function you want to mock with another function and pass the wrapper instead. Wrapping can be done in a nice and tidy way using lambda functions:

```
def year_in_range(year):
    return datetime.now().year <= year <= datetime.now().year + 10


class StudentsResource(Resource):
    args = {
        'graduation_year': fields.Int(required=True, validate=lambda y: year_in_range(y)),
    }

    ...
```

Now, when I mock `year_in_range` as stated in the question, it will work. The reason is because now a reference is saved to the lambda function, instead of to the original `year_in_range` (that won't be accessed until the lambda function runs, which will be during the test).

Answer (score 2):

By the time `mock` has patched `year_in_range` it is too late. `mock.patch` imports the module specified by the string you provided and patches the name indicated within the module so it refers to a mock object - it does not fundamentally alter the function object itself. On import of `scuevals_api.resources.students` the body of the `StudentsResource` class will be executed and a reference to the original `year_in_range` saved within the `StudentResource.args['graduation_year']` object, as a result making the name `year_in_range` refer to a mock object has no impact.

In this particular case you have a few options:

1. Assuming you're trying to test some functionality, instead of trying to mock `year_in_range` you can seed the database (?) with data that tests the condition
2. You can patch `datetime.now` which will be called by `year_in_range`
3. You can patch the member of `StudentResource.args['graduation_year']` where the function passed to `validate` has been saved.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 1 (but yeah I do use a DB) but #2 would unfortunately complicate a bunch of other things (I tried using freezegun) since there are more time-dependent things going on that are currently fine. #3 sounds good in theory but in this case it's a fairly complicated Marshmellow field class, spent a few minutes playing around with this solution but quickly realized it would take me quite some time to figure that one out as well. Anyway, I actually came up with a 4th solution (thanks to your initial explanation/hint) that I'll post as an answer here.